# In photoshop one can I find a group layer that I duplicated to another photoshop project?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Whenever I duplicate a group layer and send it to another project I can't find it unless I make the canvas bigger. is there another way so that the duplicated group appears on document screen?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have a difference in the resolutions between each file.

If, for example, you had a grouping of text that you duplicated to another file and the source file had an image resolution* of 96 pixels per inch and the destination file had an image resolution of 300 pixels per inch, the text would appear smaller in the destination file.

Also, the group will be copied to the same position in the destination file. If your view of the destination file is zoomed in outside of that, you would have to zoom out to see the copied group.

*Image, Image Size, Resolution